# Why can't you accept your own answer immediately?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, self-answer

Occasionally I ask a question for the sole purpose of sharing the answer (eg [How can I tell which files have been marked as "assume unchanged" in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27162966/how-can-i-tell-which-files-have-been-marked-as-assume-unchanged-in-git/27162975#27162975))

It strikes me as odd that I can't mark my answer as "accepted", signalling to other people that I really think that this is the actual answer, for a period of 2 days.    After all, if an even better answer comes along, I can just un-accept my own and accept that one, can't I?

The effect of this appears to be that folk who know the answer will see the question, see that it does not have an accepted answer, and therefore come to supply their wisdom, only to find that it's already there.  I can't see the upside...

Comment: Accepting an answer gives you 2 reputation points.

Comment: I guess you're saying "maybe someone will come along and write a new answer, which is good for me because even if it's the same as my own answer, I can get 2 points for accepting theirs instead of mine"?   If I wanted to do that, I guess I could always hold off accepting mine, right?     Honestly, I'd rather get rep from the question or the answer being upvoted.    I'm just imagining the people watching the tag and leaping in to a question without an accepted answer, being peeved to find it has a good answer already...

Comment: No, what I'm saying is that you could ask a question and immediately answer it continuously to gain easy rep.

Comment: You don't get rep from accepting your own answer do you?

Comment: Hmm, maybe not actually. [I guess I had that wrong.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) Ignore me.

Comment: @Sot You don't get any rep for accepting self-answers.

Comment: cross-site duplicate: [Why must I wait 2 days before accepting my own answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/6045/165773)

Answer (score 22):

I think it's because people are less likely to share their knowledge if there already is an accepted answer. Making you wait 2 days gives others a chance to propose different solutions, which may work even better.

Comment: In principle this is true, but in practice I've seen people hold off from answering self-answered questions.  Some even go as far as insinuating that it isn't a "real" question.

Comment: Well then, those people need a link over to http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: So why not apply this rule to all questions?   Why only self-answered ones?

Comment: I suggest to reduce to one day!

Comment: I answered my question, and tomorow I will forget to accept it (why I should care about it?). And question will be unanswered. Pretty stupid restriction, that generates false unanswered questions.

Answer (score 8):

> I can't see the upside...

You can't see the upside? If you look at the questions I've posted on SO (the main site, not Meta.SO), you'll see they are all self-answered. As I recall, as of *now*, they all have accepted answers. However, I've taken to leaving my self-answers unaccepted for much longer than what the system requires.

What's the upside?

I post self-answers only after I've researched the issue inside and out. So by the time I post my answer, I usually have a fairly strong certitude that my answer is *the* answer. However, I'm not omniscient. There surely are folks who have dealt with the technology involved for longer than I have. Heck, I know for a fact that the authors of some of the tools I use are reading SO and answering questions. **What if there's an even better solution than the one I found?** If I mark my answer as accepted, I'm declaring the problem solved. This reduces the chances that someone who *could* post an answer that is better than mine would even click to read my question. If I leave it unaccepted, then they may look at my question and post something better. Or they may leave a comment on my answer pointing out something I did not consider. **Everybody wins.**

Comment: I think it is disingenous to leave a question in a state where the asker knows that there is a very good answer, but the system shows the answerers that it is a question without an accepted answer.   Your argument for leaving it not marked could be applied indefinitely.  Why ever mark a solution have "accepted" - another better answer might come along.    The result of this artbitrary 2 day rule is that self-answered questions are different to other-answered questions for no good reason.