# What is the reasoning behind "You can accept your own answer [to your own question] after 2 days"?

Tags: discussion, support

I posted a question (29374778 if it matters) and then did something that magically fixed the problem when other things had not done so.

There is no need for anyone else to spend time answering, but I don't want to delete the question because someone else might have the problem. (I hadn't found any questions like it, before I posted.)

If I don't mark the question as having an accepted answer, someone might spend more time looking at the question than makes sense at this point.

The best I can do (I guess) is post a comment to the question saying that I can't mark my own answer yet.

What's the thought behind why I can't mark my own answer before 2 days go by?

Isn't one notion that if you have a problem and solve it, that you could post it as a question and then answer it? (I happened to solve it after posting it in hopes of someone else answering, but the effect is the same.)

I think that's a rather odd restriction that should go away. Are you worried that someone could ask and answer a bunch of simple questions to gain rep? Wouldn't I get the rep after 2 days if that were my goal?

Comment: And you don't get rep for accepting your own answer, so there's no need for that worry (you can still get rep other other users' votes).

Comment: duplicate of http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277960/why-cant-you-accept-your-own-answer-immediately, cross-site duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6044/why-must-i-wait-2-days-before-accepting-my-own-answer

Comment: having taken a look, there's actually a realistic chance someone will provide a better answer, which not only mentions *what* to do, but also explains *why*, which might also be valuable to you. Anyway, kudos for finding it out.

Answer (score 7):

It is to provide some time for other users to have an opportunity to post their own, potentially better, answers, to the question, and still allow for those answers to have some amount of attention.