# Name change not reflecting in data site

Tags: support, data-explorer

I have recently changed my name. I can see it was reflecting in all my posts as soon as I changed it.

But today when I was running some query in [**Stack Exchange Data Explorer**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/1037673) to check total upvotes, I could not see any results for my new name. But when I queried with old name, it was showing results. Why so?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Stack Exchange Data Explorer is updated once a week, on Sunday morning, 03:00 UTC.

Your new name will appear there in 4 days.

Instead of querying for your username, use your [userid (4295763)](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1037676/total-upvotes?usrid=4295763) in queries. That will always work, no matter future name changes.

Comment: Why i'm not able to accept the answer immediately when i knew it solved my problem? I thought of asking separate question. But i think you would know>

Comment: Because it will allow for better answers to pour in. Once a question got accepted potential answerers are reluctant to post an answer which might deprive us from higher quality / more detailed / different answers. also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277960/why-cant-you-accept-your-own-answer-immediately

Comment: I agree. But it is not the same case for all the questions right? Like this question, some facts cannot have multiple answers.

Comment: The system can't possibly know which questions are answered with a single fact.

Comment: That's true :) Thanks for answering and clarifying the other questions as well !

Comment: @ArunPalanisamy if the system was a bit smarter it would recognize that the answer was posted by rene who is always right and it would automatically mark it as accepted, but unfortunately that feature isn't implemented yet.